# Hard Regex problems: conditionals search if it passes two or all three conditionals

Tags: javascript, regex

so im having trouble writing regex in javascript.
I want to practice using conditionals on regex.

Problem i want to solve:

- combinations of (small/capital letters) + (numbers) + (special characters)
- if using two of the possible combinations, the length should be from 10-16 long
- if using three of the possible combinations, the length should be from 8-16 long

Regex for combinations:

```js
^(?=.{10,16}$)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?\W).*$
```

Comment: Regex is a tool, use it appropriately. Just because it's there doesn't mean it's the _right_ tool, and even if it is, that doesn't mean it needs to do everything all at once. Unless everything else in your application already runs at peak optimal efficiency: just do this in two steps. Test for 2 or 3, and then branch to do what needs to be done subsequently. Future you, and anyone else who has to work with the code you wrote, will thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem! You can use an OR pattern: `^((...)|(...))` where you test separately for two or three combinations. Test case:

```js
[
  '1234567890123456', // fail, only numbers
  'abcdefghijklmnop', // fail, only letters
  '12345a678',        // fail, 2 combinations, too short
  '12345a678b',       // pass, 2 combinations, 10 chars
  '12345a67890bcdef', // pass, 2 combinations, 16 chars
  '12345a67890bcdefg',// fail, 2 combinations, too long
  '12+34ab',          // fail, 3 combinations, too short
  '12+34abc',         // pass, 3 combinations, 8 chars
  '12+34567890ab$cd', // pass, 3 combinations, 19 chars
  '12+34567890ab$cde' // fail, 3 combinations, too long
].forEach(str => {
  const re = /^(((?=.{10,16}$)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]))|((?=.{10,16}$)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[\W]))|((?=.{10,16}$)(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\W]))|((?=.{8,16}$)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\W])))/;
  console.log(str + (re.test(str) ? ' => pass' : ' => fail'));
});
```

Result:

```
1234567890123456 => fail
abcdefghijklmnop => fail
12345a678 => fail
12345a678b => pass
12345a67890bcdef => pass
12345a67890bcdefg => fail
12+34ab => fail
12+34abc => pass
12+34567890ab$cd => pass
12+34567890ab$cde => fail
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `((`..A..`)|(`..B..`)|(`..C..`)|(`..D..`))` -- logical OR of parts ...A... to ...D...
- part ...A...:

  - `(?=.{10,16}$)` -- positive lookahead for 10 to 16 chars, AND
  - `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` -- positive lookahead for an upper or lowercase letter, AND
  - `(?=.*?[0-9])` -- positive lookahead for a number
- part ...B...:

  - `(?=.{10,16}$)` -- positive lookahead for 10 to 16 chars, AND
  - `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` -- positive lookahead for an upper or lowercase letter, AND
  - `(?=.*?[\W])` -- positive lookahead for a special char
- part ...C...:

  - `(?=.{10,16}$)` -- positive lookahead for 10 to 16 chars, AND
  - `(?=.*?[0-9])` -- positive lookahead for a number, AND
  - `(?=.*?[\W])` -- positive lookahead for a special char
- part ...D...:

  - `(?=.{8,16}$)` -- positive lookahead for 8 to 16 chars, AND
  - `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` -- positive lookahead for an upper or lowercase letter, AND
  - `(?=.*?[0-9])` -- positive lookahead for a number
  - `(?=.*?[\W])` -- positive lookahead for a special char

Comment: you are absolutely amazing! this helped sooo much! Im learning regex right now and this is such a great help! Thank you very much!